# Jq parsing to extract rule-number and hits.value

Tags: json, jq

I need to extract "rule-number and hits.value" from the below JSON data but I'm unable to fetch complete data using a single command.

When I use below jq command it only gives me the output of 3rd rule.

**JQ Command:**

```
jq  --raw-output '.rulebase[] | .rulebase[] | "\(."rule-number"),\(.hits.value)"' text
```

**Output:**

```
jq: error: Cannot iterate over null
jq: error: Cannot iterate over null
3,0
```

This is happening because the command is parsing twice using ".rulebase" to get the data from the 3rd rule. But by doing this it is unable to extract from the 1st ".rulebase".

Similarly, when I use below command it only extracts 1st 2 data and fails to extract the 3rd one.

**JQ command:**

```
 jq  --raw-output '.rulebase[] | "\(."rule-number"),\(.hits.value)"' text
```

**Output:**

```
1,495
2,0
null,null
```

2nd command works correctly as per my understanding but now I want to extract all the data using single command.

So, help me to get a single command to extract the required data.

**RAW JSON Data:**

```
{
  "uid" : "38271c2f-ab44-4e25-9aa4-e219cb6e12cf",
  "name" : "Network",
  "rulebase" : [ {
    "uid" : "39c3ec50-1936-40c1-a775-f6f382027b31",
    "type" : "access-rule",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "41e821a0-3720-11e3-aa6e-0800200c9fde",
      "name" : "SMC User",
      "domain-type" : "domain"
    },
    "rule-number" : 1,
    "track" : {
      "type" : "598ead32-aa42-4615-90ed-f51a5928d41d",
      "per-session" : false,
      "per-connection" : true,
      "accounting" : false,
      "enable-firewall-session" : false,
      "alert" : "none"
    },
    "source" : [ "97aeb369-9aea-11d5-bd16-0090272ccb30" ],
    "source-negate" : false,
    "destination" : [ "97aeb369-9aea-11d5-bd16-0090272ccb30" ],
    "destination-negate" : false,
    "service" : [ "97aeb443-9aea-11d5-bd16-0090272ccb30", "18ec9eaa-1657-4240-ab97-5f234623336b" ],
    "service-negate" : false,
    "service-resource" : "",
    "vpn" : [ "97aeb369-9aea-11d5-bd16-0090272ccb30" ],
    "action" : "6c488338-8eec-4103-ad21-cd461ac2c472",
    "action-settings" : {
      "enable-identity-captive-portal" : false
    },
    "content" : [ "97aeb369-9aea-11d5-bd16-0090272ccb30" ],
    "content-negate" : false,
    "content-direction" : "any",
    "time" : [ "97aeb369-9aea-11d5-bd16-0090272ccb30" ],
    "hits" : {
      "percentage" : "45%",
      "level" : "medium",
      "value" : 495,
      "first-date" : {
        "posix" : 1676788067000,
        "iso-8601" : "2023-02-19T11:57+0530"
      },
      "last-date" : {
        "posix" : 1677899191000,
        "iso-8601" : "2023-03-04T08:36+0530"
      }
    },
    "custom-fields" : {
      "field-1" : "",
      "field-2" : "",
      "field-3" : ""
    },
    "meta-info" : {
      "lock" : "unlocked",
      "validation-state" : "ok",
      "last-modify-time" : {
        "posix" : 1676788056454,
        "iso-8601" : "2023-02-19T11:57+0530"
      },
      "last-modifier" : "admin",
      "creation-time" : {
        "posix" : 1676788030368,
        "iso-8601" : "2023-02-19T11:57+0530"
      },
      "creator" : "admin"
    },
    "comments" : "",
    "enabled" : true,
    "install-on" : [ "6c488338-8eec-4103-ad21-cd461ac2c476" ],
    "available-actions" : {
      "edit" : "true",
      "delete" : "true",
      "clone" : "not_supported"
    }
  }, {
    "uid" : "751ef538-e21b-40ac-a1bf-9562c5bc3eb7",
    "type" : "access-rule",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "41e821a0-3720-11e3-aa6e-0800200c9fde",
      "name" : "SMC User",
      "domain-type" : "domain"
    },
    "rule-number" : 2,
    "track" : {
      "type" : "598ead32-aa42-4615-90ed-f51a5928d41d",
      "per-session" : false,
      "per-connection" : true,
      "accounting" : false,
      "enable-firewall-session" : false,
      "alert" : "none"
    },
    "source" : [ "97aeb369-9aea-11d5-bd16-0090272ccb30" ],
    "source-negate" : false,
    "destination" : [ "411dc962-10b5-463d-84a5-3c29aaf74858" ],
    "destination-negate" : false,
    "service" : [ "97aeb443-9aea-11d5-bd16-0090272ccb30" ],
    "service-negate" : false,
    "service-resource" : "",
    "vpn" : [ "97aeb369-9aea-11d5-bd16-0090272ccb30" ],
    "action" : "6c488338-8eec-4103-ad21-cd461ac2c472",
    "action-settings" : {
      "enable-identity-captive-portal" : false
    },
    "content" : [ "97aeb369-9aea-11d5-bd16-0090272ccb30" ],
    "content-negate" : false,
    "content-direction" : "any",
    "time" : [ "97aeb369-9aea-11d5-bd16-0090272ccb30" ],
    "hits" : {
      "percentage" : "0%",
      "level" : "zero",
      "value" : 0
    },
    "custom-fields" : {
      "field-1" : "",
      "field-2" : "",
      "field-3" : ""
    },
    "meta-info" : {
      "lock" : "unlocked",
      "validation-state" : "ok",
      "last-modify-time" : {
        "posix" : 1677291569962,
        "iso-8601" : "2023-02-25T07:49+0530"
      },
      "last-modifier" : "admin",
      "creation-time" : {
        "posix" : 1677291560424,
        "iso-8601" : "2023-02-25T07:49+0530"
      },
      "creator" : "admin"
    },
    "comments" : "For 1.1.1.2",
    "enabled" : true,
    "install-on" : [ "6c488338-8eec-4103-ad21-cd461ac2c476" ],
    "available-actions" : {
      "edit" : "true",
      "delete" : "true",
      "clone" : "not_supported"
    }
  }, {
    "uid" : "1f4dcd29-dac1-4f65-9aa3-cb0041b68c00",
    "name" : "internet rules",
    "type" : "access-section",
    "from" : 3,
    "to" : 3,
    "rulebase" : [ {
      "uid" : "df594bf8-8eee-422c-8a5f-01722fc71417",
      "type" : "access-rule",
      "domain" : {
        "uid" : "41e821a0-3720-11e3-aa6e-0800200c9fde",
        "name" : "SMC User",
        "domain-type" : "domain"
      },
      "rule-number" : 3,
      "track" : {
        "type" : "598ead32-aa42-4615-90ed-f51a5928d41d",
        "per-session" : false,
        "per-connection" : true,
        "accounting" : false,
        "enable-firewall-session" : false,
        "alert" : "none"
      },
      "source" : [ "97aeb369-9aea-11d5-bd16-0090272ccb30" ],
      "source-negate" : false,
      "destination" : [ "14745150-feab-4830-b60b-e0c39cd22758" ],
      "destination-negate" : false,
      "service" : [ "97aeb443-9aea-11d5-bd16-0090272ccb30" ],
      "service-negate" : false,
      "service-resource" : "",
      "vpn" : [ "97aeb369-9aea-11d5-bd16-0090272ccb30" ],
      "action" : "6c488338-8eec-4103-ad21-cd461ac2c472",
      "action-settings" : {
        "enable-identity-captive-portal" : false
      },
      "content" : [ "97aeb369-9aea-11d5-bd16-0090272ccb30" ],
      "content-negate" : false,
      "content-direction" : "any",
      "time" : [ "97aeb369-9aea-11d5-bd16-0090272ccb30" ],
      "hits" : {
        "percentage" : "0%",
        "level" : "zero",
        "value" : 0
      },
      "custom-fields" : {
        "field-1" : "",
        "field-2" : "",
        "field-3" : ""
      },
      "meta-info" : {
        "lock" : "unlocked",
        "validation-state" : "ok",
        "last-modify-time" : {
          "posix" : 1677291841727,
          "iso-8601" : "2023-02-25T07:54+0530"
        },
        "last-modifier" : "admin",
        "creation-time" : {
          "posix" : 1677291513151,
          "iso-8601" : "2023-02-25T07:48+0530"
        },
        "creator" : "admin"
      },
      "comments" : "For 1.1.1.1",
      "enabled" : false,
      "install-on" : [ "6c488338-8eec-4103-ad21-cd461ac2c476" ],
      "available-actions" : {
        "edit" : "true",
        "delete" : "true",
        "clone" : "not_supported"
      }
    } ]
  }, {
    "uid" : "3e6e74ef-5cdd-48b1-adc1-897bfa10974d",
    "name" : "Cleanup Rule",
    "type" : "access-section",
    "from" : 4,
    "to" : 4,
    "rulebase" : [ {
      "uid" : "2b922948-da96-4c9d-a654-063e0183f9ae",
      "name" : "Cleanup rule",
      "type" : "access-rule",
      "domain" : {
        "uid" : "41e821a0-3720-11e3-aa6e-0800200c9fde",
        "name" : "SMC User",
        "domain-type" : "domain"
      },
      "rule-number" : 4,
      "track" : {
        "type" : "598ead32-aa42-4615-90ed-f51a5928d41d",
        "per-session" : false,
        "per-connection" : true,
        "accounting" : false,
        "enable-firewall-session" : false,
        "alert" : "none"
      },
      "source" : [ "97aeb369-9aea-11d5-bd16-0090272ccb30" ],
      "source-negate" : false,
      "destination" : [ "97aeb369-9aea-11d5-bd16-0090272ccb30" ],
      "destination-negate" : false,
      "service" : [ "97aeb369-9aea-11d5-bd16-0090272ccb30" ],
      "service-negate" : false,
      "service-resource" : "",
      "vpn" : [ "97aeb369-9aea-11d5-bd16-0090272ccb30" ],
      "action" : "6c488338-8eec-4103-ad21-cd461ac2c473",
      "action-settings" : { },
      "content" : [ "97aeb369-9aea-11d5-bd16-0090272ccb30" ],
      "content-negate" : false,
      "content-direction" : "any",
      "time" : [ "97aeb369-9aea-11d5-bd16-0090272ccb30" ],
      "hits" : {
        "percentage" : "55%",
        "level" : "medium",
        "value" : 596,
        "first-date" : {
          "posix" : 1676786609000,
          "iso-8601" : "2023-02-19T11:33+0530"
        },
        "last-date" : {
          "posix" : 1677899181000,
          "iso-8601" : "2023-03-04T08:36+0530"
        }
      },
      "custom-fields" : {
        "field-1" : "",
        "field-2" : "",
        "field-3" : ""
      },
      "meta-info" : {
        "lock" : "unlocked",
        "validation-state" : "ok",
        "last-modify-time" : {
          "posix" : 1676788047995,
          "iso-8601" : "2023-02-19T11:57+0530"
        },
        "last-modifier" : "admin",
        "creation-time" : {
          "posix" : 1668629634218,
          "iso-8601" : "2022-11-17T01:43+0530"
        },
        "creator" : "System"
      },
      "comments" : "",
      "enabled" : true,
      "install-on" : [ "6c488338-8eec-4103-ad21-cd461ac2c476" ],
      "available-actions" : {
        "edit" : "true",
        "delete" : "true",
        "clone" : "not_supported"
      }
    } ]
  } ],
  "objects-dictionary" : [ {
    "uid" : "6c488338-8eec-4103-ad21-cd461ac2c472",
    "name" : "Accept",
    "type" : "RulebaseAction",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "a0bbbc99-adef-4ef8-bb6d-defdefdefdef",
      "name" : "Check Point Data",
      "domain-type" : "data domain"
    },
    "icon" : "Actions/actionsAccept",
    "color" : "none"
  }, {
    "uid" : "97aeb369-9aea-11d5-bd16-0090272ccb30",
    "name" : "Any",
    "type" : "CpmiAnyObject",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "a0bbbc99-adef-4ef8-bb6d-defdefdefdef",
      "name" : "Check Point Data",
      "domain-type" : "data domain"
    },
    "icon" : "General/globalsAny",
    "color" : "black"
  }, {
    "uid" : "14745150-feab-4830-b60b-e0c39cd22758",
    "name" : "BL_1.1.1.1",
    "type" : "host",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "41e821a0-3720-11e3-aa6e-0800200c9fde",
      "name" : "SMC User",
      "domain-type" : "domain"
    },
    "ipv4-address" : "1.1.1.1",
    "icon" : "Objects/host",
    "color" : "black"
  }, {
    "uid" : "411dc962-10b5-463d-84a5-3c29aaf74858",
    "name" : "BL_1.1.1.2",
    "type" : "host",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "41e821a0-3720-11e3-aa6e-0800200c9fde",
      "name" : "SMC User",
      "domain-type" : "domain"
    },
    "ipv4-address" : "1.1.1.2",
    "icon" : "Objects/host",
    "color" : "black"
  }, {
    "uid" : "6c488338-8eec-4103-ad21-cd461ac2c473",
    "name" : "Drop",
    "type" : "RulebaseAction",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "a0bbbc99-adef-4ef8-bb6d-defdefdefdef",
      "name" : "Check Point Data",
      "domain-type" : "data domain"
    },
    "icon" : "Actions/actionsDrop",
    "color" : "none"
  }, {
    "uid" : "97aeb443-9aea-11d5-bd16-0090272ccb30",
    "name" : "https",
    "type" : "service-tcp",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "a0bbbc99-adef-4ef8-bb6d-defdefdefdef",
      "name" : "Check Point Data",
      "domain-type" : "data domain"
    },
    "port" : "443",
    "icon" : "Protocols/HTTP",
    "color" : "red"
  }, {
    "uid" : "598ead32-aa42-4615-90ed-f51a5928d41d",
    "name" : "Log",
    "type" : "Track",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "a0bbbc99-adef-4ef8-bb6d-defdefdefdef",
      "name" : "Check Point Data",
      "domain-type" : "data domain"
    },
    "icon" : "Track/tracksLog",
    "color" : "none"
  }, {
    "uid" : "6c488338-8eec-4103-ad21-cd461ac2c476",
    "name" : "Policy Targets",
    "type" : "Global",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "a0bbbc99-adef-4ef8-bb6d-defdefdefdef",
      "name" : "Check Point Data",
      "domain-type" : "data domain"
    },
    "icon" : "General/globalsAny",
    "color" : "none"
  }, {
    "uid" : "18ec9eaa-1657-4240-ab97-5f234623336b",
    "name" : "ssh",
    "type" : "service-tcp",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "a0bbbc99-adef-4ef8-bb6d-defdefdefdef",
      "name" : "Check Point Data",
      "domain-type" : "data domain"
    },
    "port" : "22",
    "icon" : "Services/TCPService",
    "color" : "red"
  } ],
  "from" : 1,
  "to" : 4,
  "total" : 4
}
```

Comment: A possible solution would be to use `.rulebase[]? // .` for the second filter, i.e., `jq '.rulebase[] | .rulebase[]? // . | "\(."rule-number"), \(.hits.value)" '`

Comment: Can you please let me know from where I can learn such kind of parsing techniques to grow my knowledge on jq usage.

Comment: I just used the [jq manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) - my reasoning was that since there are two types of objects you'll need some form of [conditional](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ConditionalsandComparisons) - reviewed those and found `//` to be the easiest way to deal with a possibly non-existing property (second `.rulebase`) and since `.rulebase[] // .` was not working I recalled the `.[]?` operator from the "Basic filters" chapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first version is close; the problem arises at the second filter, i.e., the second `.rulebase[]`.

My understanding is that the second `.rulebase` (i.e., `.rulebase.rulebase`) may exist or not; if it exists, it replaces the first `.rulebase` for the source of data (`.rule-number` and `.hits.value`).

For this case the simplest solution seems to be the alternative operator `//` from the [Conditionals and comparisons](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ConditionalsandComparisons) chapter in the manual.

Also, since you have to index the possibly non-existing property `.rulebase`, you'll need to employ the `.[]?` operator instead of plain `.[]` (described in the [Basic filters](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters) chapter).

The alternative to the missing second `.rulebase[]?` is keeping the original one (the result of the first filter), that makes the second filter `.rulebase[]? // .` and
the overall solution:

```
jq '.rulebase[] | .rulebase[]? // . | "\(."rule-number"), \(.hits.value)"'
```

Comment: Thanks @kikon, that was very informational. I have tested your command on a original and huge data and it works perfectly. Thank you very much for your help. :)